# Como atribuir arredondamento no button e cores aleatórias ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: android

Opa galera, estou com uma dúvida já dei uma vasculhada na internet e ainda não encontrei talvez não seja possível, mas vamos lá..

Por exemplo eu tenho um button nesse button eu jogo cores aleatórias nele, tenho uma List List Cores = new ArrayList(); e nessa list eu guardo as cores em Hexadecimal, até ai sem problemas eu uso o  Collections.shuffle() e pego uma cor aleatoriamente da lista e no button uso o bt1.setBackgroundColor(), minha dúvida maior é eu to querendo que meus buttons de minha aplicação fiquem com os cantos arredondados, sei que tenho que usar algo como isso

cantosredondodos.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#33DDFF" />
    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
</shape>
```

mas se eu colocar esse xml como background lá no xml do button

```
<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:background="@drawable/cantosredondodos"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

o backgroud que defini antes no código vai sobrescrever o a parte do xml que eu quero pra fazer o radius, teria alguma solução? pra fazer tudo no código da aplicação?, eu até pensei em fazer vários xmls mas acredito que não ficaria muito legal, como eu tenho mais de 10 buttons não ficaria uma coisa muito viável...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode definir a borda programaticamente usando `shape.setStroke(3, borderColor)`, onde o `3` representa a borda e `borderColor` representa a cor da borda usando o [**`GradientDrawable`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html). Veja esta função abaixo, que passo como parâmetro a `view`, que seria seu botão, o `backgroundColor` e a `borderColor`. Veja:

```
public static void customView(View v, int backgroundColor, int borderColor){
    GradientDrawable shape = new GradientDrawable();
    shape.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
    shape.setCornerRadii(new float[] { 8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0 });
    shape.setColor(backgroundColor);
    shape.setStroke(3, borderColor);
    v.setBackgroundDrawable(shape);
}
```

Você pode fazer a customização conforme suas ideias.

Para definir uma cor aleatoriamente você pode usar a classe [**`Random`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Random.html). Veja:

```
Random rnd = new Random(); 
int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
```

Comment: opa obrigado, aqui no meu caso eu dei uma pequena adaptada :  ic void customView(int backgroundColor, Button valor){
        shape = new GradientDrawable();
        shape.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
        shape.setCornerRadii(new float[] { 8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0 });
        shape.setColor(backgroundColor);
        //shape.setStroke(3, borderColor);
        valor.setBackgroundDrawable(shape);
    }   as cores eu já tenho adicionadas na lista ao todo 18 cores, e no meu caso eu já uso o collections.shuffle para não repetir as cores, mas obrigado resolveu meu problema

Comment: @RogersMarques legal... eu coloquei assim pra você adaptar mesmo, porque está de um jeito bem genérico.  abs. boa sorte